# Display an image from a file location

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to show an image from a location in my public directory.  In my model I have created a path for the image but when I call it in the show action it simply displays the string.

```
  def img_path
"<img src='/system/assets/10/original/airplane.jpg'>"
  end
```

Here is the html:

```
      <td>&lt;img src='/system/assets/10/original/airplane.jpg'&gt;</td>
```

Comment: you should look at the second answer below as it's a "better" solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `raw` to unescape html

```
<%=raw img_path %>
```

It's part of the security measures built-in Rails

Comment: Is it possible to set that path dynamically?  Say with something like  
"<img src='/system/assets/' + '#{self.id}'+ '/original/' + '#{self.filename}'>"

Comment: you'd better do: "<img src='/system/assets/#{self.id}/original/#{self.filename}'>"

Answer (score 5):

The best way to do it is that your model defines an image_path method

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  def image_path
     "/system/assets/#{id}/original/#{filename}"
  end
end
```

and in a helper or in the view you can do something like

```
<%= image_tag(image.image_path) %>
```

Where image is the instance of the type Image

This way you won't have to deal with escaping and unescaping issues.

Comment: I'd agree that this is a better solution, why embed you're presentation code in your model when there's a helper in your view for it.